# Can not install libpng12.so.0 on Ubuntu 19.04 for Packet Tracert 7

Tags: apt, 19.04

I've faced this issue in the earlier Ubuntu's versions and was able to install `libpng12.so.0` without any problem.

But in the latest Ubuntu 19.04 I cannot install it...

What I have tried:

1. Download and installed it locally

   ```
   wget -q -O /tmp/libpng12.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb && dpkg -i /tmp/libpng12.deb   && rm /tmp/libpng12.deb
   ```
2. Created a symlink

   ```
   ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0
   ```
3. Added new repository and installed via `apt`

   ```
   echo “deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/ xenial main” >> /etc/apt/sources.list
   apt update
   apt install libpng12-0
   ```

All these workarounds don't work.

Could someone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Define don't work, what went wrong?

Comment: I'm getting the following error: 
./PacketTracer7: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Works OK here : `sudo apt install libpng12-0` ... ... `Get:1 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libpng12-0 amd64 1.2.54-1ubuntu1 [116 kB]` ... so the package is actually in "main". ( One search said 'xenial-security', the other 'xenial-updates'.)

Comment: Doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 12):

I finally got what was causing the error, and fixed it.

You can download the new packages here:

> https://www.dropbox.com/s/79x3imq73tcqyw4/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1b_amd64.deb?dl=0
>   https://www.dropbox.com/s/yhk1p83b2e7rvt4/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1b_i386.deb?dl=0

So, basically the problem comes from the architecture of the packet and the architecture of Ubuntu's /lib and /usr/lib folders.
On the previous releases /lib and /usr/lib were 2 distinct folders, but on Ubuntu 19.04 /lib is a symlink to /usr/lib.

Now, take libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb as an example.
This is the deb architecture (I'll show only the binaries):

> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (symlink)
>   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.54.0
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (symlink)

This creates a conflict when unpacking in Ubuntu 19.04 because it tries to write two times libpng12.so.0 at the same place, which is impossible with apt.

What I did is simply a repacking of the files with this architecture:

> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0 (symlink)
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng12.so.0.54.0

If you don't trust my packages (and I would understand), you can simply compare the checksums of the files with those from the original packet.

Comment: Thanks, but I wouldn't download a package from a random post and I wouldn't expect anyone else to either. Can you [edit] to explain what the problem was and how you fixed it, please?

Comment: You're right, I'll explain what I did.

Comment: Thank you so much! worked for me...

Comment: I had to download and complied the source and copy the files to the locations

Comment: Fill some details. Get deb from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/arm64/libpng12-0/1.2.54-1ubuntu1 [or whatever platform]. Unpack with "mkdir tmp; dpkg-deb -R ./libpng12-0.xxx.deb tmp". Remove extra link "rm -r usr/lib". Repack with "dpkg-deb -b tmp libpng12-0.deb". And install as usual "sudo dpkg -i ./libpng12-0.deb". Tested on Ubuntu 20, NVidia Jetson (ARM).

Answer (score 3):

Download libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb, extract it, then copy libpng12.so.0, libpng12.so.0.54.0 from data.tar.gz folder to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

Comment: now I have this error: `./PacketTracer7: ./libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ./PacketTracer7)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)` I haven't found solutions of how to fix it.

Comment: I had to download and complied the source and copy the files